# Past perfect example confusion

Tags: tenses, past-tense, perfect-aspect

My text definition of past perfect tense tells me that it is used to refer to an action that is completed at some point in the past and before the commencement of another past action. I came across this example : We had stopped the car. 
I know this example is past perfect tense but shouldn't there be another past action along with it to be called as past perfect? Please answer..

Comment: It's important to know the context of the sentence. You're right about the past perfect tense denoting a completed past action taking place before another past action. However, that second past action doesn't need to occur in the same sentence or even the same paragraph, and sometimes it's just implied (someone might say, "Well, I had wanted to leave work early today," and to me that might imply that something came up (after the desire to leave early, but before the present) to interfere with that desire, but we're not given to know what that is). So context is important.

Comment: For exam how can one understand whether they are implying something when only a single sentence is given ? Could you explain it some more?

Comment: Well, implication automatically depends on context. In the work example I gave, if that's the only sentence offered, the context is the general concept that people don't like work and would enjoy leaving early, and also that, since the speaker used the past perfect, something else must have occurred afterward.

If the speaker isn't trying to imply anything, he should just use the simple past--"I wanted to leave work early." His use of the past perfect automatically suggests that it happened before some other past event, but we're left to guess at what that might be.

Comment: Using the past perfect itself doesn't require the simple past in the same sentence. You can use the past perfect on its own, and that's totally correct English. However, you should be aware of the fact that using the past perfect will almost always lead the listener/reader to assume you're trying to imply something (which would normally follow in the simple past).

Comment: So the only way to identify whether the given sentence is past perfect or not is to look for 'had + past participle' and there doesn't need to be the simple past sentence along with it?

Comment: Exactly. The past perfect isn't dependent upon anything else; if you see "had + participle," you're looking at the past perfect.

Comment: That's the **name** of the construction: Past tense of _have_ followed by Past participle of `Verb` marks the Past Perfect construction (not "tense"). That's not how it's used or whether it should be used or what it means; it's just the name of a recognizable construction. There are hundreds more constructions, most of which are more common than the Past form of the Perfect construction, which is part of the [auxiliary verb train in the Verb Phrase.](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of past perfect in a narrative is to set the scene for other occurrences that happened in the past, too, but after the thing expressed in past perfect. But the followup action need not be included in the same sentence in order to justify the past perfect. Consider this example:

> We had stopped the car. Snow continued to fall lightly on the roadway, but the slender wet band of pavement remained visible, like a flat black brook winding its way through the dusted fields.

The author here could have said simply "We stopped the car." But using "We had stopped the car" at the outset puts a greater distance between the moment when the car stopped and the moment when the narrator, having taken in or recollected the scene, begins to describe it.

I can't think of a situation where using past perfect without any reference to simple past would make sense, but past perfect definitely does not have to share space in the same sentence with simple past (for example) in order to do its job.